# pandas: Check if 2 columns exist in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if BOTH 'Rating' and 'Grp' are in df2.columns. Oddly, I get 'yes' although I have dropped 'Rating'. Thank you

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Grp': ['a' , 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                    'Rating': ['H', 'L', 'L', 'H']
                    })

df2=df2[['Grp']]
if 'Rating' and 'Grp' in df2.columns:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: This does not work as you think: `if 'Rating' and 'Grp' in df2.columns`

Comment: My above question is not working as expected be'cos it should be if 'Rating' in df2.columns and 'Grp' in df2.column. The other query is for "OR" condition which differs from my query. Thanks